# Add smb4k shares using a script

Tags: scripts, samba, shared-folders, kde5

I tried to find any command line options, import/export actions, or a config file that could be copied but I could not find a way to add smb4k shares by script.

So, is there a way to add smb4k shares using a shell script? Where does smb4k store the share settings?